# Змейка на js - вопрос по коду

Tags: javascript, jquery

В js не силен, поэтому решил попрактиковаться.
В видео я покажу, что именно происходит, словами это сложно объяснить)
Ниже привожу код, обратите внимание, код не полный, лишее для вопроса я убрал, мне нужно понять только то, что не выходит.

Видео  https://youtu.be/4M7jzAjz2T4

```
function moveSnake(cl)
{ 
        var x=$(".snakedeye").data("x"); // голова
        var y=$(".snakedeye").data("y"); // голова  - тут все данные верные - считываются из элемента верные


if (cl=="right")
    {
        var newx=x+1;
        var newy=y;
    }
    else if (cl=="down")
    {
        var newx=x;
        var newy=y+1;
    }

// etc
    $(".row"+y+".col"+x).attr("data-nextx",newx);//здесь пишем данные для туловища, куда им надо идти, когда они дойдут до этой клетки
    $(".row"+y+".col"+x).attr("data-nexty",newy);// и здесь


    $(".row"+y+".col"+x).html(newx+":"+newy);
var cilcle=0;

var snaked = $(".snaked");

$(".snaked").each(function(index,value)

{ 
    // а внутри этого цикла все данные старые, хотя в коде они уже новые
    var th=$(this);

    var thisx=th.data("x");
    var thisy=th.data("y");

    var thisnewx=th.data("nextx"); //здесь 
    var thisnewy=th.data("nexty"); // и здесь данные получаются старые
})
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ. Хочу обратить внимание, данный код пишется для саморазвития, не надо предлагать какие-то готовые решения, я понимаю, что их полно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не смешивайте вызовы `data` и `attr`. Это не работает.

```
//$(".row"+y+".col"+x).attr("data-nextx",newx);
//$(".row"+y+".col"+x).attr("data-nexty",newy);          
$(".row"+y+".col"+x).data("nextx",newx);
$(".row"+y+".col"+x).data("nexty",newy);
```

https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

> Since jQuery 1.4.3, data-* attributes are used to initialize jQuery
>   data. An element's data-* attributes are retrieved the first time the
>   data() method is invoked upon it, and then are no longer accessed or
>   mutated (all values are stored internally by jQuery).

То есть

> Начиная с jQuery 1.4.3, атрибуты `data-*` используются для
>   инициализации данных jQuery. Атрибуты `data-*` элемента извлекаются в
>   первый раз, когда вызывается метод `data()`, а затем к ним больше не
>   обращаются (все значения хранятся внутри jQuery).

Comment: я не понял Вашего ответа. значения в числа - какая разница, если я получаю старые данные?

Comment: @Ozim1 Не смешивайте вызовы data и attr.

Comment: с помощью attr( я устанавливаю значение, а с помощью data получаю, в чем проблема? как это влияет на ситуацию?

Comment: @Ozim1 https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: @Ozim1 Это влияет на ситуацию очень плохо.

Comment: @Ozim1 данные получаемые с помощью метода data кэшируются, то есть хранятся в самом JQuery. Поэтому вы можете получить данные которые не ожидаете. Используйте метод data для изменения значения в JQuery или attr для получения атрибута из DOM. В первом случае вы уменьшаете количество запросов к дереву элементов.

Comment: Спасибо ребят, работает! даже подумать не мог, что такое может быть))